# MVC - Areas and Controllers Confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dry, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm architecting an **MVC 5** web application in Visual Studio. I have added an **Area** to the project which will contain functionality which is specific to users within the role of Administrator.

However, there is similar functionality and Views needed by both Administrators and Default users. For example, take this

```
MyProject --> Controllers --> MyController --> MyActionResult
MyProject --> Areas --> Admin --> Controllers --> MyController --> MyActionResult
```

Both Controller folders contain an ActionResult which contains the same logic and returns the same View. The Views will return a **Partial View** which can be reused hence helping with the **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, however, I am wondering the following

1. If both ActionResult methods have the same logic and return the same
   View, then is there a need for both methods? Violation of DRY principle etc?
2. Would it be better if when the Administrator needed to access this particular method, they were directed to

   MyProject --> Controllers --> MyController --> MyActionResult

And set this method to allow access to Administrators

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public ActionResult MyActionResult(int id)
{

}
```

1. Or is this some kind of violation, i.e., the users in Administrator
   role should only be viewing pages within the Area that was setup for
   functionality specific to them?

Any help or advice with this would be greatly appreicated, we always try to follow best practices in our development team.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like my areas to be domain or sub-domain specific - not user or security specific.  Annotate your methods/classes with Authorize annotations, as you've already mentioned.

```
If both ActionResult methods have the same logic and return the same View, then is there a need for both methods? Violation of DRY principle etc?
```

I'd say no, you don't need both and it is a violation of DRY

```
Would it be better if when the Administrator needed to access this particular method, they were directed to

    > MyProject --> Controllers --> MyController --> MyActionResult
```

Absolutely, I think this is better and a best practice

```
Or is this some kind of violation, i.e., the users in Administrator role should only be viewing pages within the Area that was setup for functionality specific to them?
```

No way.  We always have granular security with Domains and Sub Domains.  Use your authorization annotations to control access.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the issue correctly I would consider a base controller that contains the shared functionality and the additional code can be added to the admin area controller.

In regard to the view I would just use some c#/vb code to only display certain code if user is an administrator

such as:

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole( "Administrator" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Common area which isn't actually routed to but contains functionality common to multiple areas. You can keep shared views there and share controller methods via inheritance.